# ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor executeNow();

Tags: java, android

How can I tell ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(let's call him sht) to execute his task when a button is pressed ?

For example if I have something like this :

```
sht.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
         method1();
         method2();
         method3();
    }
}, 0, 5, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
```

The methods that are inside sht will execute every 5 minutes but what I want to do is to run them "at now" . I can't just call the methods because some reasons.

I need something like this :

```
sht.executeNow();
```

Comment: Do you want it to run now in addition to every five minutes or only on demand?

Comment: Now, and after that, at every five minutes.

Comment: The code as you have posted it should work, with an initial delay value of 0 specified...

Comment: Yeah, the methods are executed immediately but what I want is after this first execution(with 0 delay) to be able to execute the task on a button press . So  I want to execute that methods(1,2,3) between the interval set for sht ( 0 - 5 minutes).

Comment: Ok, so you should be able to achieve that with the base `execute()` method.

Comment: So I would do something like sht.execute(new Runnable(){method1();method2(); method3()};) . But what will happen with the main tasks ? They will execute after 5 minutes from sht.execute() or something else ?

Comment: Submitting a new task for execution should have no effect on any previously submitted/scheduled tasks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58157/discussion-between-george02-and-corsair992).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The base `execute()` method of the `Executor` interface allows queuing tasks for immediate execution. You should hold a reference to the scheduled `Runnable` task and submit it for immediate execution on the click of the button.

In case you want to reset the scheduling after the button is clicked, you can do that by removing the previous `Runnable` task via the `remove()` method and rescheduling it. The `execute()` method would not be needed in that case, as you can achieve immediate execution by specifying an initial delay value of 0 in your scheduling method.

Considering your simple use-case, you might want to look at using a `Timer` instead of `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor`, as it provides a much simpler API for what you are attempting. In fact, unless you really need to run these tasks in another `Thread`, you should use a `Handler`, which will manage the scheduling and execution of the tasks without needing to start new `Thread`s.